# AppleScript: when concatenating a POSIX path a comma is inserted?

Tags: file, path, applescript, posix, path-separator

I have this code

```
tell application "Finder" of machine "eppc://db@air.local"
    open POSIX file "/Volumes/tmp/" & fileName
end tell
```

but when I execute it I get an error and log looks like this:

```
tell application "Finder" of machine "eppc://air.local"
    open {file "Macintosh HD:Volumes:tmp:", "myfile 1:1.txt"}
        --> error number -10010
end tell
```

**Why?**

The file is there but I wonder about the `Macintosh HD` part of the path. The volume is named that but in a POSIX path you start with `/`, not `Macintosh HD`, don't you? Also, I wonder about the "broken up" file path `"Macintosh HD:Volumes:tmp:", "myfile 1:1.txt"` - this doesn't look right?

(`tmp` is remote volume so it is correct that it is mounted under `/Volumes/`)

Note that the filename contains a colon.

Comment: A `POSIX path` is text, but `POSIX file` evaluates to a file object, so the concatenation results in a _list_.  Note that colons are used as delimiters in Finder file paths.

Comment: @red_menace Yes? I don't get your point.

Comment: I don’t have an external volume with mixed path delimiters for an answer, but a comma is not being inserted, the concatenation is resulting in a _list_. The error is because you are trying to open a list consisting of `POSIX file "/Volumes/tmp/"` (a file object) and the `fileName` string.  `POSIX file` evaluates to an HFS file object, which uses colons for delimiters and includes the volume name.  To use colons in the file name you would need to stick to POSIX paths, which rules out the Finder (and also avoids the whole `POSIX file` coercion/concatenation issue).

Comment: @red_menace It's not a problem. Both notations handle any literal occurrence of their own delimiter by substituting out that of their counterpart. The file name should use the colon when in POSIX notation, and a slash when in HFS notation. The OP has ir correctly exoressed here.  The issue is mostly one of parentheses (and a secondary issue of inheritance around the  `POSIX file` specifier): _`open my POSIX file named ("/Volumes/tmp/" & fileName)`_ will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need coercion **as Posix file** instead of specifier.

```
tell application "Finder" of machine "eppc://db@air.local"
    open ("/Volumes/tmp/" & filename) as POSIX file
end tell
```

Or, move the specifier out of Finder tell block:

```
set filename to "160094_full.jpeg"
set posixFile to POSIX file ("/Volumes/tmp/" & filename)

tell application "Finder" of machine "eppc://db@air.local"
    open posixFile 
end tell
```

The fact is that this specifier is a concept of a script, not a Finder application. This leads to the 3rd possible solution --- using the **me** keyword:

```
set filename to "160094_full.jpeg"

tell application "Finder" of machine "eppc://db@air.local"
    open (POSIX file ("/Volumes/tmp/" & filename) of me)
end tell
```

Comment: I understand your code, it is obvious and I feel stupid ;-), but what do you mean by coerce in this context?

Comment: Inside a Finder tell block, this specifier (**Posix file**) will not work. Either you should move it outside the block, or apply coercion (**as Posix file**).

Comment: I added 2 other working variants.